# Is it allowed to run NM wire in PVC pipe under an outdoor porch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, outdoor

I would like to know if it's allowed to run 10/3 Romex in 3/4 inch PVC pipe for 15 ft. outside under the floor of an open porch to be wired to a 30A power outlet for a portable 6500 watt generator.

Answer (score 2):

No. Nonmetallic sheathed cable is not allowed in wet locations.  NEC considers outdoor conduit a wet location.

You'll have to use THWN conductors, or other conductors/cables rated for wet locations.

If you use THWN conductors, you'll be able to fit 7 conductors through 3/4" Schedule 80 PVC ([Table C.9](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/41481/33)), or 9 conductors through 3/4" Schedule 40 PVC ([Table C.10](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/41481/33)).

Comment: 10/3 UF-B is [$2 a foot at the orange borg](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-10-3-UF-B-W-G-By-the-Foot-13059199/204632775?N=5yc1vZc57bZ1z0zueaZ1z10mzf)...